# How to filter in excel based on many unique values?

Tags: excel, filtering

I have a lot of data in my excel sheet, I want to filter my data based on the telephone number keyword, for example:

I have the following numbers:

```
530547XXXX
310548XXXX
530518XXXX
```

where `X=` the rest of the number but I'm hiding them for privacy purposes.

I want the filter to only give me the rows that contain those numbers.

Comment: Cant you use Data filters?

Comment: I have 200,000 rows and I need to filter 500 rows (Numbers)

Comment: can you share sample data?

Comment: In MS Office 2010, select the data you want to filter. Then go to Data>filter. In Row 1, a drop down arrow will appear with the filter options

Answer (score 0):

You can use advanced filters.

1. Make sure that you label all column headers;
2. In a separate area, put the same column header as your telephone # column;
3. Under that new header put the telephone # you want to filter for.
4. In 2007 (and I think 2010 too) go in the Data tab and then in the "Sort & filter" group click on the arrow in the bottom right corner for Advanced filtering.
5. Select the data range with headers and then select the filtering range with headers.

This will enable you to filter with more than one criteria at once (just put more columns if you want). The way it works is that if you put more than one column in the criteria range, it will filter for rows meeting both criterias on the same row. What I mean is that if you say in one row that telephone # must be X and that name must be Y then it will look for both at the same time, not separately.

[Filter by using advanced criteria](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-HP005200178.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You *might*, if you wanted to and depending upon what data you have other than that shown above, be able to flag the rows that contain telephone numbers with a 'helper' column (say A) containing something like `=IF(ISNUMBER(B1),"Tel","")` in Row1 and copied down. Then filtering that column for `Tel` may pick out the require telephone numbers. This might work if the 'other' rows say contain address elements (anything but numeric only). I'm afraid it would not suit if your entire column is of numbers.

However if your entire column is numbers but you have a list of those of special interest (say in a columnar range called `Tel`) then instead of the formula above you might apply `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,Tel,1,0),"")` so that only your selected numbers are chosen if you filter for everything but blanks in ColumnA.